# adding a new field age in admin page

Tags: python, django

i have a family_member model in django that has a set of attributes, i want to calculate age based on date_of_birth, so basically i want to add a column next to date_of_birth with age, and what i've done

models.py

```
class FamilyMember(models.Model):
    transaction = models.ForeignKey(Transaction, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    family_group = models.ForeignKey(FamilyGroup,
                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                    null=True,
                                    blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    relationship = models.ForeignKey(Relationship, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    dependant_child_age_range = models.ForeignKey(DependantChildAgeRange,
                                                null=True,
                                                blank=True,
                                                on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    care_percentage = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        null=True, blank=True, validators=[
            MaxValueValidator(100),
        ])
    income = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6,
                                decimal_places=2,
                                null=True,
                                blank=True,
                                help_text='''Excluding:
1. Maintenance
2. FTB-A & FTB-B
3. CRA
but incl. ES(1) for all payments and FTB-A & FTB-B''')
    rent_percentage = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        null=True, blank=True, validators=[
            MaxValueValidator(100),
        ])

@property
def age(self):
    from math import floor
    
    return floor(
        (datetime.today().date() - self.date_of_birth).days / 365.25)
```

admin.py

```
class FamilyMemberInline(admin.TabularInline):




def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    action = request.META['PATH_INFO'].strip('/').split('/')[-1]
    if action == 'change':
        transaction_id = request.META['PATH_INFO'].strip('/').split('/')[-2]
        if db_field.name == "family_group":
            kwargs["queryset"] = FamilyGroup.objects.filter(transaction=transaction_id)
    return super(FamilyMemberInline, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
model = FamilyMember
extra = 0

def sufficient_info_provided (self, obj):
    return obj.sufficient_information_provided
sufficient_info_provided.boolean = True

def get_age(self, obj):
    return obj.age

readonly_fields = ['sufficient_info_provided','get_age', ]
```

but now i get this error :`unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.date' and 'NoneType'

i've tried to include If statment in the age function if date_of_birth is None: pass

but still not working`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`date_of_birth` is nullable. What's happening is that you're encountering an instance that has `instance.date_of_birth == None`. One way to handle this in `age`:

```
@property
def age(self):
    from math import floor
    if self.date_of_birth:
        return floor(
            (datetime.today().date() - self.date_of_birth).days / 365.25)
```

However, I do want to say calculating the age as you are here isn't the best way to do it. It's a reasonable approximate, but you can fairly easily get the actual age by annotating your queryset and using the database's features. If you're using postgresql, here's a tutorial on it's [AGE](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-age/) function. You can then supply `AGE` to a `Func` in the [annotation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions).